# Prevent macOS app from staying in 'Recent' section of Dock

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nswindow, dock

My application is an Agent (doesn't show up in dock) until one specific window is shown, before showing that window I set the following to let the dock display the icon:

```
NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.regular)
```

When the window gets closed I set the following to hide the icon from the dock:

```
NSApp.setActivationPolicy(.accessory)
```

It works on most of the machines, however on others the app icon stays in dock in 'Recent' section with **no** 'active' indicator. I can manually remove it via right click and selecting 'remove from dock' but it appears again the next time the window is open. Is it even a 'Recent' section? What's the API to either remove the app from there or prevent it from being added to dock when it's open?
Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to change to NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular? This is the reason why it's displayed in the dock. Only non sandboxed apps can modify preferences of Dock

Comment: @MarekH I change it to NSApplicationActivationPolicyRegular so the app appears in dock when the window is shown. However when it's closed - i set it back to .accessory, because part of it is still running but I don't want the icon to stay in dock forever. The problem is that the icon remains visible in a 'recent' section no matter what activation policy it has.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Vimy it's still a mystery. I think it's a bug of macOS